# Java replaceAll escape characters into double escape

Tags: java, android, regex, replace

I have a string value which received from input field.

```
String searchingText = getText();
```

After i receive a string i search this string. But if string contains `\` symbol my search is failed.

I know about special characters and try to replace :

```
searchingText = searchingText.replaceAll("\\","\\\\");
```

But it give me error and app was shutdown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
```

After research i founded a regex and try to replace with matcher :

```
    Map<String,String> sub = new HashMap<String,String>();
    sub.put("\n", "\\\\n");
    sub.put("\r", "\\\\r");
    sub.put("\t", "\\\\t");

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\n|\\r|\\t");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(bodySearchText);
```

In the end i will want to get a string - `searchingText = \\` instead of `searchingText = \`

Please any solutions.

Comment: "But it give me error and app was shutdown" - what is the error/exception? Please post stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Note that in Java, `\` is written as `\\`. So [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will see `\\` as `\`, which is not what you want.

Instead, you can use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) that accepts String and not a regex.

Comment: Shouldn't `replace()` be enough?

Comment: I have a solution, but your answer is almost right. I will edit it.

Comment: I will accept this at 6 minutes. sistem blocked this action because i have little value of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
searchingText = searchingText.replaceAll("\\","\\\\");
```

to

```
searchingText = searchingText.replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\");
```

the `replaceAll()` will take `\\` as `\` .

for more details read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)